# Not able to convert the csv to HTML in Jmeter

Tags: java, linux, cmd, jmeter

I am running load test on one of my sftp server application using jmeter. I run my jmx script as below

```
nohup sh jmeter.sh -n -t <jmx_file> -l <jtl_file> &
```

Script does have **Simple Data Writer** which creates csv file with result, which i convert into html using below command running on cmd from bin folder of jmeter.

```
jmeter -g <csv_path> -o <html_folder>
```

It was working couple of days back and now if i run the above command it gives error as below

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
errorlevel=3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

There was an update in my jdk from 1.8_241 to 1.8_251 and i have updated my **java_home** as well.
Do i need to do anything else in jmeter to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Double check that you can launch JMeter normally without nohup like:

   ```
   ./jmeter.sh --version
   ```
2. Ensure that the test is producing the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) and the file is up to date and not from the previous executions
3. Check the contents of [*nohup.out* file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)
4. In general you [should not be using any listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing), it is sufficient to have the .jtl results file in order to generate the dashboard and [the dashboard can be generated during the test run](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t <jmx_file> -l <jtl_file> -e -o <html_folder>
   ```

   if you don't have any background logic to remove "stale" jtl_file and html_folder you will need to add `-f` command-line argument to force JMeter to overwrite the old result file and dashboard folder like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -f -t <jmx_file> -l <jtl_file> -e -o <html_folder>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i need to use nohup in order to run the command in background and yes the command to generate html worked fine. But one more query which i have is, while using sftp.get() the result shows different number of files downloaded where as jmeter logs show different number files downloaded which is equal to the number of files actually downlaoded. I am not sure why html report show different number. i have added the script in question. please let me know if i am missing anything